# Creating a Google authentication service with users stored in own database in Golang

Tags: go, oauth-2.0, jwt, openid-connect

First step in creating my new suite of react frontend applications is to make a simple Authentication server/service in Go preferably, where users can authenticate with their google account which will either result in:

- creation a new user in the database
- login if matching user is found in db (how to determine match without password?)

I realize that I will get a JWT from the Auth server/service with the usual claims such as:

```
{
    "iss":"accounts.google.com",
    "at_hash":"HK6E_P6Dh8Y93mRNtsDB1Q",
    "email_verified":"true",
    "sub":"10769150350006150715113082367",
    "azp":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "email":"jsmith@example.com",
    "aud":"1234987819200.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "iat":1353601026,
    "exp":1353604926,
    "nonce": "0394852-3190485-2490358",
    "hd":"example.com"
}
```

So far so good, but after that I'm not really sure what fields I need to store for the user "table" (using a dgraph db, but I guess it doesn't matter if it's a relational or graph db) in the database other than the email, which will to my understanding be the identifier pairing the user in db with the JWT?

How do you handle integration with your own database:

1. First time a user authenticates with google through the auth server/service and a user is created in the db
2. Subsequent times a user authenticates with google  through the same auth server/service and logs in (already exists in db - but how to verify this in a safe way - couldn't others just make a false token with the same email?)

Do you store the token in the user table along with the email? In that case what to do if the token expires/changes and what about security?

So the question is not about how to get a token, it's about how to connect the user in the db with the JWT user that just got authenticated.

Most tutorials and articles I've read does not describe the database part in much detail.

Comment: Not marking for closure since there's a lot here, but "recommendation regarding libs" is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry you're right. Deleted it.

Comment: It really depends on what information you need about users. If you need to remember permissions, preferences, whatever, store that. Otherwise just an email should do until you need more.

Comment: I can easily query for groups, roles and permissions or whatever in the graph database afterwards and put it in redux. I'm not a fan of putting unnecessary stuff in jwt. It's the connection with the db that i'm interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Creation a new user in the database**

In principle, you only really need to store the user's email (along with whatever other information your system needs internally for that user) to be able to 'link' your user with the "external" account they are using to login.

**Login if matching user is found in db (how to determine match without password?)**

One of the main reasons to rely on an external authentication mechanism is that you don't need to perform any password storage/validation yourself.

You just need to match the email the user is using to authenticate with the email you have stored in your DB.

**Couldn't others just make a false token with the same email?**

No, they cannot, otherwise this would not be useful at all.

Tokens are signed by the authentication server, and it is not possible to "sign" the token without having the authentication server's private key.

**How to verify this in a safe way**

See here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Section "Verify the integrity of the ID token" discusses how you do this either by yourself or by calling an external endpoint.

**Do you store the token in the user table along with the email?**

You only need to store the user's token if besides authenticating them you plan to use Google's APIs on behalf of the user.

**In that case what to do if the token expires/changes and what about security?**

See here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

You will need to store both a token and a refresh token, and there is a flow to follow in order to refresh it.

About security, you need to make sure no user is able to see other user's token, since the token enables an application to make requests to the API on behalf of that user.

Comment: Thanks for listing up and answering all my questions ;-).

Comment: One more question. Since you say the email is used for creating the user in the database or "linking" an already existing user after a login, is it correctly understood that OpenID will not be sufficient, since the JWT received from OpenID does not contain email info? I only need one key to identify the user in the database - and then I will fetch (from the db) the user info I need into redux or whatever state management solution. So that leaves OpenID Connect and OAuth2? I only want the minimum user info in JWT that I need to match it against that same user in the database, so which is best?

Comment: @Dac0d3r: this link describes the same flow for OpenID: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect, take a look at the "Obtain user information from the ID token" section.